# IAnimal Interface implemnted by Dog and Cat and DogViewmodel and catViewModel takes IAnimal dependency. How to inject correct obj cat to CatViewmodel

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, interface

I was asked the below problem in interview of injecting the correct type in dependency injection. I told i will use factory pattern and check the type before injecting the object. Then interviewer asked me if there are 100 classes will you do for all the classes. then he gave hint to use Ienumerable. But I did not get the solution. Below explained the problem statements. Please help me to understand the solution for the below problem.

in WPF MVVM pattern
Model : Has an Interface called IAnimal and two classes are implementing it.

```
public class Dog : IAnimal
{
}
public class Cat : IAnimal
{
}
```

in viewmodel having two classes CatViewModel and DogViewModel

```
public class CatViewModel
{
    public CatViewModel(IAnimal animalObj)
    {
    }
}

public class DogViewModel
{
    public DogViewModel(IAnimal animalObj)
    {
    }
}
```

here DogViewModel should take only DogModel object and CatViewModel should take only CatModel Object. Here constructor is having IAnimal type so there can be posibility of injecting wrong object. How to protect and inject correct type.

Comment: `DogViewModel should take only DogModel object and CatViewModel should take only CatModel Object` then why are they accepting an IAnimal?

Comment: What are the restrictions given? Are you able to refactor the provided code. The design as shown is poor (code smell) and will cause unnecessary complications. Was this a trick question by the interviewer. There are too many unknowns with the way this post is currently presented. This makes it difficult to clarify the actual problem here

Comment: Hi @McNets, The Interviewer asked me to take in any form like in constructor or property or through method, But It takes IAnimal I want to give catModel for CatViewModel. I don't know the approach so I mentioned here with constructor. He gave a hint to relate with IEnumerable. He asked me to related this problem with IEnumerable. I gave answer that I will put   where T : CatViewModel. He then asked where will you do this in method or constructor or CatViewModel. I don't know the answer. If these points helps you to get some more context towards problem help me to understand this.

Comment: @Nkosi I accept this is poor coding and also tricky question from the interviewer. I have added the above comments. If that gives some more idea to you please help me to understand what way we can do. If anymore clarification required please let me know. I will try my best to answer.